# reuse parts of template

Tags: mustache, ractivejs

I have a template like below

```
<div>
    <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{linkText}}</a>
    same duplicate link below 
    <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{linkText}}</a>
</div>
```

As you can see above `<a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{linkText}}</a>` is being reused two times. Is there any possible solutions to define it once and use it as many times as I need.

Comment: Mustache is by-design a low-power language, so abstractions like that don't seem to be possible. There are some good comments about why using a more powerful language for templates is a good idea in the presentation here: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/05/06/flux.html

Answer (score 3):

You could either use `Partials` or `Components` to achieve this. Here is an example using `Partials`

http://jsfiddle.net/GdVz8/

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
<div>
    {{>link}}
    same duplicate link below 
    {{>link}}
</div>

<!-- {{>link}} -->
    <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{linkText}}</a>
<!-- {{/link}} -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage mustache iteration.

```
<div>
    {{#links}}
    <a href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}">{{linkText}}</a>
    {{/links}}
</div>
```

But you need your data to repeat.

```
{
    "links" : [{
        "href" : 1,
        "class" : 1,
        "linkText" : 1,
    },{
        "href" : 1,
        "class" : 1,
        "linkText" : 1,
    }]
}
```

Comment: Come on buddy... I hope you read the question again. It's not about lists.

Comment: Before there were multiple anchors in the template, now there is only one.  So the template is less redundant.  Lists are a way of doing it, but if there is a reason why lists aren't a good solution then you need to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: I solved this by using Partials :) And your answer is also valid, but if I want to follow another approach.